# reading innerHTML of HTML form with VALUE attribute (& its value) of INPUT tags

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a `html` `form` with some input fields.

Instead of reading and sending the values of `input` fields by `document.ipForm.userName.value` , I need to send the whole html content to html parser and extract the `<name ,value>` pair of each input field by some other program( and other information too).

But when i did this in JavaScript(i want pure JavaScript- not other library)

```
var contents=document.getElementById("formArea").innerHTML;
alert(contents);
```

It **doesnot shows** the `value="enteredValue"` of `<input/>` fields even if i entered some values.

My HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showInnerHtml(){
        var contents=document.getElementById("formArea").innerHTML;
        alert(contents);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formArea">
        <form name="ipForm" >
          UserName : <input type="text" name="userName"> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div> other contents.....   </div>
    <div onclick="showInnerHtml()">Show InnerHTML</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i missing something here or this is not possible.

Don't call me MAD. but i am struggling with this strange condition.

Comment: As far as I know, the `value=""` stuff in .innerHTML will never reflect what you've entered into an input field after the page has loaded. It'll only contain what was present in the value="" at the time the page was loaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because `value` is a property when the textbox is filled in, not an attribute. This means that `.value` works fine, but it's not part of the actual DOM as an attribute (like `<input value="...">`).

You'd need to set it explicitly:

```js
document.getElementById("html").onclick = function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("ipForm")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    // set attribute to property value
    elems[i].setAttribute("value", elems[i].value);
  }

  alert(document.getElementsByName("ipForm")[0].innerHTML);
};
```

```html
<form name="ipForm">
  UserName : <input type="text" name="userName">
</form>
<button id="html">get innerHTML</button>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkjhZ/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write an input which will change itself his attribute, like this :

```
(...)

UserName : <input type="text" name="userName" onChange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);">
```

And for checkboxes :

```
onClick="if (this.checked) { this.setAttribute('checked', null); } else { this.removeAttribute('checked'); }"
```

Enjoy :)