# wrong values with JS innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<div id='html'><input type='text' value='' /></div><br><a onClick="alert(document.getElementById('html').innerHTML);">click me</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EQ88q/

If you change input value and click on "click me" you won't see the real input value. Is there any propety instead of "innerHTML" that gets the real values?

PS: I'm using plain javascript I can't use any library.

Comment: Just `value` will do, although you will have to find the child element (the input) as well: http://jsfiddle.net/EQ88q/2/

Comment: `document.getElementById('html').innerText`

Comment: @GolezTrol yeah, but I need the whole "html" code not only the input value. Isaac innerText returns "undefined".

Comment: innerHTML gets the html of the element as it is in the DOM. The value you typed in it isn't included.

Comment: Here is an exact duplicate question which provides an answer: [reading innerHTML of HTML form with VALUE attribute (& its value) of INPUT tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601851/reading-innerhtml-of-html-form-with-value-attribute-its-value-of-input-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but it is quite crude:

```
<div id='html'>
<input type='text' value=''/>
</div>
<script>
function LinkClick()
{
 var ele = document.getElementById('html');
 ele.children[0].setAttribute("value",ele.children[0].value);
 alert(ele.innerHTML);
}
</script>
<br><a onClick="LinkClick()">click me</a>
```

---

I see ComCrude just [provided this exact answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601851/reading-innerhtml-of-html-form-with-value-attribute-its-value-of-input-tags) in the comments

Comment: It works, I will leave this as my last choice... I think it should be a property to get what I need...

Answer (score 0):

The `elem.innerHTML` is the HTML code inside of the element. In this case, the `innerHTML` is empty string as there is no content inside the  tag.

You should use `input_elem.value` to obtain the `value` property of a input element.

Comment: Noooo goood nooo. I don't want the input value. I want "html" innerHTML with the correct input values.

Comment: @Isaac's solution would work for you. I understood what you want finally.