# Inserting into database table with auto generated numbers through javascript

Tags: java, javascript, php, mysql, sql

I Have created a from for my website. My form posts into two separate tables, namely: `'members'` and `'users'`

My form seems to input into my database fine, apart from under **Membership Type** `'membershipnumber'`. My membership number is auto generated using javascript.

Please can someone help me and point me in the right direction as to why this isnt working and how i can get it to work.

```
<form action="receptionist.php" method="post">
         <td align="center" style="background-color:lightblue;"><b>-Personal Information-<br></td> </b>
    </p>
      <tr>  
       <td align="left"> Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
        <td></td>
       <td align="left"> Medical Information: <input type="text" name="medicalinformation"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
      <td align="left">  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
    <td></td>
      <td align="left">Membership Type: <select name="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
                            <option value="">Select One</option>
                            <option value = "Gold">Gold</option>
                            <option value = "Silver">Silver</option>
                        </select></td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
       <td align="left"> Date Of Birth: <input type="text" name="dateofbirth"><br></td>
            <td></td>
      <td align="left">  Gender:<input type ="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male 
                <input type ="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female<br>
            </tr>
        <td align="left">Membership Referral: <input type="text" name="membershipreferral"><br></td>
        <td></td>
       <td align="left"> Trainer Required: <input type ="radio" name="trainerrequired" value="Yes"> Yes 
                          <input type ="radio" name="trainerrequired" value="NO"> No<br></td>

            </tr>

    <td align="left"> Membership Number:</td>
    <td align="left" id="xyz"><input type="text" name="membershipnumber" disabled></td>
    <script>
       var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
       document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML=num;
</Script>

       <td align="left"> Contract: <input type ="radio" required> Agree <br></td>
</tr>
      <td align="left">
         Please select contract duration 
         <select name="contract" id="contract">
             <option value="">Select One</option>
             <option value = "1 month">1 month</option>
             <option value = "2 month">2 month</option>
             <option value = "3 month">3 month</option>
             <option value = "4 month">4 month</option>
             <option value = "5 month">5 month</option>
             <option value = "6 month">6 month</option>
             <option value = "7 month">7 month</option>
             <option value = "8 month">8 month</option>
             <option value = "9 month">9 month</option>
             <option value = "10 month">10 month</option>
             <option value = "11 month">11 month</option>
             <option value = "12 month">12 month</option>
                                        </select><br></td>
</tr>
</tr>
</br>

       <td align="center" style="background-color:lightblue;"><b>-Address-<br></td> </b>
    </p>
</tr>
        <td align="left">House Number/Street: <input type="text" name="housenumberstreet"><br></td>
        <td></td>
       <td align="left"> City: <input type="text" name="city"><br></td>
</tr>
     <td align="left">   County: <input type="text" name="county"><br></td>
        <td></td>
     <td align="left">   Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode"><br></td>
</tr>
       <td align="left"> Tel: <input type="text" name="tel"><br></td>
           <td></td>
     <td align="left">   E Mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br></td>


        </tr>
        <td align="center" style="background-color:lightblue;"><b>-Billing-<br></td> </b>
    </tr>
    </p>
       <td align="left"> Bank Branch: <input type="text" name="bankbranch"><br></td>
</tr>
       <td align="left"> Card Holder Name: <input type="text" name="cardholdername"><br>        </td>
    </tr>
        <td align="left">Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardnumber"><br></td>
        <td align="left">Sort Code: <input type="text" name="sortcode"></td>

</tr>
       <td align="left"><font size="3.2" color="red"><b>Valid From</font><br> </b>
                    Valid Month <select name="validmonth" id="validmonth" required>
                                                <option value="">Select One</option>
                                                <option value = "January">January</option>
                                                <option value = "February">February</option>
                                                <option value = "March">March</option>
                                                <option value = "April">April</option>
                                                <option value = "May">May</option>
                                                <option value = "June">June</option>
                                                <option value = "July">July</option>
                                                <option value = "August">August</option>
                                                <option value = "September">September</option>
                                                <option value = "October">October</option>
                                                <option value = "November">November</option>
                                                <option value = "December">December</option>
                                        </select>
                    Valid Year <select name="validyear" id="validyear" required>
                                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                                <option value="2007">2007</option>

                                        </select><br></td> 
</tr>
         <td align="left"> <font size="3.2" color="red"><b>Expiry</font><br> </b>
                    Expiry Month <select name="expirymonth" id="expirymonth" required>
                                                <option value="">Select One</option>
                                                <option value = "January">January</option>
                                                <option value = "February">February</option>
                                                <option value = "March">March</option>
                                                <option value = "April">April</option>
                                                <option value = "May">May</option>
                                                <option value = "June">June</option>
                                                <option value = "July">July</option>
                                                <option value = "August">August</option>
                                                <option value = "September">September</option>
                                                <option value = "October">October</option>
                                                <option value = "November">November</option>
                                                <option value = "December">December</option>
                                        </select>
                    Expiry Year <select name="expiryyear" id="expiryyear" required>
                                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                <option value="2013">2015</option>
                                                <option value="2012">2016</option>
                                                <option value="2011">2017</option>
                                                <option value="2010">2018</option>
                                                <option value="2009">2019</option>
                                                <option value="2008">2020</option>
                                                <option value="2007">2021</option>
                                        </select><br></td>
</tr>
       <td align="left"> Security Code: <input type="text" name="securitycode"><br></td>
        </tr>

        <td align="left"><p style="background-color:lightblue;">
        Please double check entered information and tick box to proceed
        <input type="radio" required></br></td>
</tr>
       <td align="left"> <input type="submit"></td>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just replace

```
<td align="left" id="xyz"><input type="text" name="membershipnumber" disabled></td> 
this line to 
<td align="left"><input type="text" id="xyz" name="membershipnumber" disabled></td>
```

this line.

everything your code snippet is ok.

Hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following post might answer your question: [reading innerHTML of HTML form with VALUE attribute (& its value) of INPUT tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601851/reading-innerhtml-of-html-form-with-value-attribute-its-value-of-input-tags).

In short: Setting the value attribute explicitly using "document.getElementById("xyz").setAttribute("value", num);" should work. See the above-mentioned post for further details with regards to why innerHTML wouldn't work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good catch, @moinul - didn't notice that one :-).