# Dropdown selected value is showing wrong while printing as window.print()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when  i am trying to print my html dropdown selected value is showing wrong.
here my drop down box details are

```
A
B
C
```

in the above when i am trying to print after selected `B` it is showing `A` only.
Always it is showing `A`.

```
var printContents = angular.element('#pdfId').html();
var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
    frameDoc.document.write(printContents);
window.frames["frame1"].print();
```

Comment: please post your code and template.

Comment: always it is showing first value in printing or in pdf

Comment: var printContents = angular.element('#empalternativaheaderpdf').html();

Comment: var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>

Comment: post your code to your qustion by edit it. don't add details in comments.

Comment: frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title><link href="css/Copyofalternativa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(printContents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();

Comment: I have the same problem, but after post back, the select value is printed, I did not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select id="dropdown">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
</select>
<script>
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
console.log(dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value);    
</script>
```

Comment: is your dropdown ID `pdfId`? If so, you shouldn't be calling .html() on it

Comment: no. actually i am printing a jsp page which contains so many divs all are printing .but dropdown selected value is showing wrong in pdf

Comment: As I understand `pdfId` is page wrapper and that wrapper contains form elements, so you're trying to fetch all content of page with values of form fields, but I don't think it will work for select tag, as it doesn't have `value` property. 
Maybe this is useful reference for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601851/reading-innerhtml-of-html-form-with-value-attribute-its-value-of-input-tags