# how to print a data from input fields to hard copy?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am creating a project and want to print data that I put in input field on to hard copy ...

How can I do that?

for example:
If I have a table with input fields and I will input data into the field using browser, now, as soon as I am done with input, I want to print that information. (CODE UNDER), I took this code from W3schools: When I press print button, it prints the webpage.. but it does not print the information that is given to it...

How can I do that>

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Print form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="myfrm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <br> Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<p align="center"><input type="button" onclick="myPrint('myfrm')" value="print"></p>
<script>
    function myPrint(myfrm) {
        var printdata = document.getElementById(myfrm);
        newwin = window.open("");
        newwin.document.write(printdata.outerHTML);
        newwin.print();
        newwin.close();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading innerHTML of HTML form with VALUE attribute (& its value) of INPUT tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601851/reading-innerhtml-of-html-form-with-value-attribute-its-value-of-input-tags). In short, "value is a property when the textbox is filled in, not an attribute ... not part of the actual DOM"; but you can "set it explicitly".

Answer (score 0):

You are copying over the HTML, but not the field values, the code below will do the trick.

See that the input fields now have Id's and we copy them over right before `newwin.print()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Print form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="myfrm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="first">
        <br> Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="last">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<p align="center"><input type="button" onclick="myPrint('myfrm')" value="print"></p>
<script>
    function myPrint(myfrm) {
        var printdata = document.getElementById(myfrm);
        newwin = window.open("");
        newwin.document.write(printdata.outerHTML);
        newwin.document.getElementById("first").value = document.getElementById("first").value;
        newwin.document.getElementById("last").value = document.getElementById("last").value;
        newwin.print();
        newwin.close();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```